# Keep Checking until True

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a form that is handled by a CMS which I cannot edit it's javascript, but I more or less want to add in a "Loading" or "Sending" message to my users. For example.

Currently, the default form once submitted, will append a html success message to a div called 'success' once sent, but basically, I want to run a function on the submit button that keeps checking the 'success' for anything other than '' and once it isn't empty, turn off the loading symbol.

Something like this perhaps:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    $('#loadingDiv').show();
    while (!$('#success').html() == ''){
        $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just not quite sure how to write it, I'm not great with jquery or javascript

Comment: Don't use UI changes as event triggers for control; instead, attach to whatever is triggering the UI change.

Comment: As I stated above, I don't have control over the CMS.

Comment: Javascript provides you with callbacks, thus eliminating the need that you perform while (true), except for very rare cases. If you are submitting a form use jQuery.post ($.post) and utilize the success callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do this with setInterval. Something like this:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    $('#loadingDiv').show();
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if($('#success').html() != '') {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            $('#loadingDiv').hide();
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

while (!$('#success').html() == '') will freeze all other operations and will last forever.
But still - it is better to double check if you really can't add some code into success callback. Possibly [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) may help you.

Comment: Did the trick very nicely, Just a simple UI visual, but works quite well, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could send the form's data manually with something like this?

(In this case, maybe make sure that "submitBtn" is a simple button and not a submit button to prevent the default submit)

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    $('#loadingDiv').show();

    // Send the data with post - To complete
    $.post('/your_post_addr', {data_1: my_data_1, ...}, 
        function(data) {
            $('#loadingDiv').hide();          
    }).error(function() {
        // Your error message
        alert('Error'); 
    });
});
```